# Android FIrebase Query populate FirebaseListAdapter 2 nodes below

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

*Update 2 - 12/21 - The following is now working to return just the nodes I want. All that's left is to get the POJO details (5 records) in each of the following nodes into the FirebaseListAdapter. See the code at the bottom of this post, `messageText.setText(model.getSubscriberNickname());` is bringing back null because the POJO is another node lower.

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("userposts").child("TEST");

Query query = myRef.orderByKey()
        .startAt("1495522799000")
        .endAt("1495954799000");
```

*Update 1 - 12/21 - When I use the following reference, I get the 4 desired POJO fields displayed in the UI for a single node/key("1495954799000"). However, I want the same result across multiple nodes/keys. Hence, my desire to use startat/endat. I need help with the startat/endat statement syntax.

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("userposts").child("TEST").child("1495954799000");
```

I want to use `FirebaseListAdapter`. I have a very simple `FirebaseListAdapter` example already working without the .startat/.endat and with just 3 properties. What I don't know how to do is query, jump down a node level and put the `POJO` in the `FirebaseListAdapter`.

I want to now implement `FirebaseListAdapter` with the following existing structure. I have a `POJO` as my Model named "Post" I left off the `POJO` detail below (beneath the bottom-most node) because the `POJO` has many properties. There are multiple nodes at the "TEST" level. Beneath this level are millisecond dates that end at the latest second of each day. Beneath this is a custom key and beneath that is the `POJO`. There is only 1 `POJO/Model` beneath each of the custom keys (with the &s).

My code is functional in that it brings back from `Firebase` the keys just below TEST. All properties in the `UI` are blank because the `POJO` is not yet getting populated.  What I want is to filter these keys just below TEST (i.e. bring back the last 4 days), ignore the keys with the &s at the next lower level, and stuff  the `POJOs` from under each date and display 4 fields from the `POJO` in the list `Adapter`.

(I don't care about the time = "HH:mm:ss" just yet. Will fix that later)

The screenshot below shows both the Firebase structure (black) and the data I want to retrieve (red). Ultimately I want 4 properties from the POJO to be represented in the FirebaseListAdapter.

[image]

Here's some code:

```
private FirebaseListAdapter<Post> adapter;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("userposts")

    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
myRef.child("TEST")
    .startAt(1495522799000L)
    .endAt(1500188399000L);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Post>(this, Post.class,
            R.layout.message, myRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Post model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            TextView messageLeg = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_leg);

            messageText.setText(model.getSubscriberNickname());
            messageLeg.setText(model.getLegName());
            messageTime.setText("HH:mm:ss");
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageText());

        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what do you want to retrieve exactly?

Comment: @Peter Haddad - thanks. I want to retrieve these POJOs: .1495522799000
 1495419709728&2
 POJO
1495954799000
 1495912289972&2&
 POJO
 1495912512690&2&
 POJO
 1495912601320&2&
 POJO
 1495914851254&2&
 POJO

Comment: @Peter Haddad - I modified the screen shot in the original post to illustrate what I am attempting to retrieve. The POJO has approximately 20 properties in it. I want four of these (listed in the code above) in the FIrebaseListAdapter and ultimately on the UI.